# What does “Polked” mean in “We Polked you in ‘44”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, culture, history, pun

I came across this phrase/sentence:

> We Polked you in ’44, we shall Pierce you in ’52! <sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we%20shall%20Pierce%20you%20in%20%E2%80%9952%20but%22)</sub>

I googled "Polked" but all it gives me is "poked", so I had the crazy thought that it might be the joining of the words "poll" AND "poked" as a way of saying "We in poll poked (f**ked) you."

Does that make any sense?

Comment: The initial capital in Polk and Pierce gives it away. They are proper names. Try looking them up again with that clue.

Comment: What @mdewey said. Note that the whole *point* of the pun depends on the fact that being ***poked*** (perhaps just by a wagging reproachful finger) is far less serious that being ***pierced*** (perhaps by a sword through the heart). Which enables the slogan to wittily imply ***We only beat you before, but we're going to resounding thrash you this time**!*

Comment: The source answers the question, if you just click on it.

Comment: What's the actual source? You linked a search, and Google searches can vary by location, by user, and over time for that matter. Although, it only has [one result](https://books.google.ca/books?id=mBF9iQvhJ_kC&pg=PA174&dq=%22we+shall+Pierce+you+in+%E2%80%9952+but%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnntGIjtnxAhUxNX0KHePCA1EQ6AF6BAgCEAI) for me right now.

Answer (score 30):

Like mdewey commented, "Polk" and "Pierce" are proper nouns referring to, respectively, [James K. Polk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_K._Polk) and [Franklin Pierce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Pierce).

Polk was the Democratic Party nominee in the 1844 Presidential election, which he won. Pierce was the Democratic Party nominee in the 1852 Presidential election.

Separately, "poke" and "pierce" are both verbs that convey the image of something prodding or sticking something else, which can be used negatively if some person is the one being poked (or pierced). "Polk" is pronounced similarly to "poke" and "Pierce" is, of course, pronounced the same as "pierce."

So "We Polked you in '44; we shall Pierce you in '52!" is a **campaign slogan** in the form of a **pun** playing on the fact that Polk won the 1844 election and (so the slogan claims) Pierce will resoundingly win the 1852 election. The "you" could refer to the party's political opponents or to the country as a whole.

Comment: I would say that the pronunciations of "Polk" and "poke" are similar but not the same. The "l" isn't really pronounced as a distinct sound but it strongly affects the sound of the vowel.

Comment: This is like that campaign in 1976 (or was it 1980?) where someone had a slogan like "*Don't put the Carter before the horse*" - only I forget who they were referring to as "the horse" in this case...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Carter lost to Reagan in 1980. Reagan acted in a number of cowboy movies.

Comment: There have also been puns on "Trump" - for example the anti-Trump slogan "love trumps hate".

Comment: There have been quite a few others, but the one that’s caught on the most is “OK,” for “Old Kinderhook,” the birthplace of Martin Van Buren. (The word was already in vogue as a facetious misspelling, “Orl Korrekt,” before Van Buren’s supporters appropriated it.)

Comment: @Barmar I think it was more literal than that - like someone ran an actual horse against him in the primaries as a gag, or something like that.  Tried looking it up, but all I kept finding were references to "dark horse" candidates...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._presidential_campaign_slogans#1976) doesn't show that slogan in either of the presidential campaigns against Carter. Maybe it was in one of his campaigns for lower offices.

Comment: Since this is an international site, and English learners can be learning English in any country, maybe add "U.S." to qualify "Presidential election"?

Comment: @MarkFoskey It's ok to edit responses when something is obviously wrong but otherwise everything is a solid answer.

Comment: @shoover You could edit that in as well but it's probably just as well that they get used to "presidential election" referring to the US as the only major Anglosphere country with an important president, just like Spanish speakers need to make peace with America referring to the US instead of the two continents of North and South America.

Answer (score 1):

Funny that you should bring this up now.  Gail Collins in her weekly column in the *New York Times* also referenced this old campaign slogan that you're referring to, just two days ago.  I hope this gives a little more context:

[Pondering Presidents — Who Got ‘Polked’?](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/07/07/opinion/trump-worst-presidents.html)

She writes:

> Franklin Pierce spent most of his administration trying to stave off
> political turmoil by being wishy-washy on slavery. He died an
> alcoholic, a project he was already working on long before he hit the
> White House.
>
> On the plus side, one of Pierce’s great political advantages was that
> he was extremely attractive — his nickname was “Handsome Frank.” This
> should be a good lesson to all of us who worry that the mass culture
> is sinking — even in 1852, the electorate was perfectly capable of
> picking a leader who was terrible but cute.
>
> And if you want to move on to unedifying campaign slogans, here’s one
> from the Democrats: “We Polked you in ’44, We shall Pierce you in
> ’52.”